# A couple of questions about Lyapunov functions

Tags: lyapunov-functions

Consider the dynamical equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$.

1. Is $V(x) = x^{1+\alpha}$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ a Lyapunov function?
2. Since $x(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$, would a function $V(y) \not\in \mathbb{R}_+$ for $y \not\in \mathbb{R}_+$ still be a Lyapunov function?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: One example: $V(x) = x^{1.5}$.  This $V$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and its derivative is as well.  They are both undefined (well, not real) for $x < 0$.  Is such a $V$ still a Lyapunov function?